# How does c++ choose move and copy construct

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor, typeid, typeinfo

I'm working out an "Any" class by myself. As following code shown, I have two questions.

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Test{};

class Any {
 public:
  template<typename DataType>
  explicit Any(DataType&& in) {
    Test t;
    std::cout
        << typeid(t).name() << "  "
        << typeid(in).name() << "  "
        << typeid(Test()).name();
    std::cout << " move";
  }
  template<typename DataType>
  explicit Any(const DataType& in) {
    Test t;
    std::cout
        << typeid(t).name() << "  "
        << typeid(in).name() << "  "
        << typeid(Test()).name();
    std::cout << " copy";
  }
};

int main()
{
  Test t;
  Any a(t);
}
```

Compilation command is

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11
```

The output is

```
4Test  4Test  F4TestvE move
```

1. Why does c++ choose move construct rather than copy construct? "t" is an instance of Test which it's not a rvalue.
2. Why typeid(in) and typeid(Test()) is not same? They are both rvalue.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first constructor has an "universal reference" (look it up) as the parameter, so it can accept any value category, and you don't need the other one. Note that those are not copy/move constructors, because the parameter types are not references to `Any` itself.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why does c++ choose move construct rather than copy construct? "t" is an instance of Test which it's not a rvalue.

The 1st constructor overload takes [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) and could accept both lvalues and rvalues. (Hence it's not move constructor.) For `Any a(t);` it's an exact match, while for the 2nd overload `t` needs to be converted to `const`.

> 2. Why typeid(in) and typeid(Test()) is not same? They are both rvalue.

`Test()` is a function type, which returns `Test` and takes nothing, thus `typeid(Test())` gives different result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your move variant is invoked is because its signature doesn't actually require an rvalue reference to be passed.

If `U = T const&` then `U&&` will be a `T const&`, not a `T&&`. In your case `DataType` binds to `Test&`, not, as you likely expected, to `Test`. The `&&` therefore collapses and does nothing. You can see this in action if you add a `static_assert(std::is_same_v<DataType, Test&>);` which will pass.
You function will be called if you replace the template with a fixed Type, i.e. `Test&&` instead of `DataType&&`.

Have a look at [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference), section Reference collapsing.